# Microdata for product images which aren't displayed in the page?

Tags: images, google-index, html5, microdata

My internet shop displays thumbnails of products' images, and I see that these thumbnail are (slowly) being indexed by Google. I want also full images to be indexed.

Can I use Microdata for this? Something like this:

```html
<meta itemprop="image" content="/uploads/images/medium/product_img.jpg" />
```

Or:

```html
<meta itemprop="image" src="/uploads/images/medium/product_img.jpg" />
```

Would it do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="/uploads/images/medium/product_img.jpg">
```

Since `src=""` is associated with embedding content on the page and content="" is associated with embedding items off the page so to speak. This is the same method as used with the Facebook Open Graph meta as well, take a look:

```
<meta property='og:image' content='/uploads/images/medium/product_img.jpg'/>
```

Comment: Ant this is the confirmation I was looking for. I will try it, and hopefully Google will index these images, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the value is a URL, you [must use `link` instead of `meta`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669).

```html
<link itemprop="image" href="/uploads/images/medium/product_img.jpg" />
```