# Do search engines follow the additionalType url in microdata?

Tags: seo, html5, microdata, schema.org

For example

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
        <meta itemprop="additionalType" content="http://www.productontology.org/id/Long-distance_running">
    </div>
```

If so, which vocabulary(?) is more descriptive?

`productontology.org`
`dbpedia.org`
`wikipedia.org` ?

Comment: Note that you [must use `link` instead of `meta`](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82115/17633) because the value is a URI: `<link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Long-distance_running" >`

Answer (score 2):

*Follow* as in *visit*? Probably not.

In `additionalType` you specify a URI that represents a type.

- If a search engine supports this type, it has no need to visit it (because it already knows what it needs to know when seeing the URI).
- If a search engine doesn’t support this type, it *could* visit its URI, learn something about it (via RDF), and make use of it, but as far as I know there is no general Web search engine that does this (specialized Linked Data / Semantic Web consumers do this).

You shouldn’t use an URI just because its page represents what you want to convey. Instead you should use URIs from vocabularies, which provide RDF to specify that they are meant to be used as classes and ideally describe the meaning.

So the [Product Types Ontology](http://www.productontology.org/) and [DBpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/) are suitable candidates (and there are [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669)), but Wikipedia isn’t one. Which one to use can’t be answered in general. It always depends on your content and the consumers you expect to make use of it (i.e., what they support).